# PDO search query with multiple parameters

Tags: php

Below is my code.

I am trying to create search query with multiple parameters in php pdo....with Multiple if else condition in a single query.

but the between query won't fetch any records, what i'm doing wrong??

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){

            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM sales';
            $where = array();
            $params = array();

            if (!empty($_POST['startdate']) && !empty($_POST['enddate'])) {
                $where[] = "submitdate BETWEEN :a AND :b";
                $params[':a'] = $_POST['startdate'];
                $params[':b'] = $_POST['enddate'];
            }

            if (!empty($_POST['recordstatus'])) {
                $where[] = "status = :status";
                $params[':status'] = $_POST['recordstatus'];
            }

            if(count($where) > 0)
                $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode('AND', $where);

            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);

            foreach($params as $param => $value) {
                $stmt->bindParam($param, $value);
            }
            $stmt->execute();

            for($i=0; $row = $stmt->fetch(); $i++) {
                echo $row ['submitdate'];
                echo $row['status'];
            }
```

Comment: Can you show us what your query finally looks like when assembled?

Comment: What exactly does "won't work well" mean?  Are you getting errors?  If so, what are they?  If not, then what _is_ the problem?  Are you getting results that are different from what you expect?  If so, what are the expected results and what are the actual results?

Comment: the issue is that i can only fetch the records that has the same enddate if i used the previous binding method..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add extra spaces in your `implode()` glue string :

```
$sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
```

Because you could have :

```
"submitdate BETWEEN :a AND :bANDstatus = :status" // Bad query
```

Optionnaly, you also could wrap with brackets if you have `OR` statements, and tests if your array is not empty :

```
if (!empty($where)) {
   $sql .= ' WHERE (' . implode(') AND (', $where) . ')' ;
}
```

Will gives you :

```
"WHERE (submitdate BETWEEN :a AND :b) AND (status = :status)" // Good query
```

Comment: unfortunately i couldn't fetch any record using the previous binding method,  but only the records that has the same enddate.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the following:

1. Add parenthesis to the BETWEEN statement:

   ```
    (submitdate BETWEEN :a AND :b)
   ```
2. Check the date format
3. Add spaces to the 'AND' in your implode.